# Array to string conversion, what to do?

Tags: php, arrays, string, select, fetch

I'm having problems with the  Array to string conversion error. 
It's occurring here:

```
 <div id="pagename">
       <?php echo ['SELECT name FROM hjemmesider']; ?>  
   </div>
```

I'm trying to fetch a row from my db and display it, but i can't make it work... I have tried tons of things to try and sort it out, and of course researched it a great bit on the internet.

Comment: You need to add far more detail to your question! Do you have some example data from your db? Examples of what you've tried?

Comment: This is PHP/MySQL 101 and there are [thousands of tutorials online](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+data+from+mysql+in+php).

Answer (score -1):

in your `foreach` or `while` use `echo $row['your_field_name'];`

You are not doin it right.. try like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It most probably means that you are trying to echo an Array. Use `print_r` function on your result and things will get clearer.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: when i wrote the 'comment' the text of the question was a different one